# How to compare field values from a List in Apex

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I need to compare field values of a list of records in my object and get the aggregated value based on some conditions

**For example:**

```
Parent__c parent = [Select id, currency__c from Parent__c where id =: someId];

List<my_cust_obj__c> custObjs = [Select id,rank__c, currency__c,parent__c, parent__r.currency__c, Name from my_cust_obj__c where parent__c =: someId];

List<my_cust_obj__c> custObjs1 = [Select id,rank__c, currency__c,parent__c, parent__r.currency__c, Name from my_cust_obj__c where parent__c =: someId];
```

I get around 5 records from this query. Now I need to compare `rank__c` of each record with the other record and populate value on the `parent__r.currency__c` based on the least `rank__c`. If there are multiple records with same `rank__c` then I need to show the aggregate sum of the `currency__c` values on the child to parent record. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved. I tried below:

```
Integer x;
for(my_cust_obj__c custObj: custObjs){
  for(my_cust_obj__c custObj1: custObjs1){
    if(custObj.currency__c == custObj1.currency__c){
            x = custObj1.currency__c+custObj.currency__c;
    }else if(custObj.currency__c < custObj1.currency__c){
            x = custObj.currency__c;
    }else if(custObj.currency__c > custObj1.currency__c){
            x = custObj1.currency__c;
    }
  }
}
parent.currency__c = x;
```

Is this approach correct or am I making it complex? Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: I think you are probably over-complicating things here, but we need additional information to suggest a better approach. In your example, are `custObj` and `custObj1` really lists containing the same SObject? Or do you have two separate SObjects that are both related to your `Parent__c` SObject?

Comment: @DerekF In simple terms, I have a list of records in a child object which i filter based on parent Id (one parent with multiple child records in child object) . There is a field in this child object which is like a grade to each record. So based on this grade I need to populate currency field on parent, if there are two or more child records with same grade, i need to identify all child records with least grade, add up the currency value of these least grade child records and show it on parent currency field

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really answer my question. What are the actual names of the SObjects that you're working with here? Do you have a single child SObject, or two child SObjects?

Comment: Please just answer the question I'm asking you. Literally just "Do you have a single child SObject, or two child SObjects?". That's the important piece of information that we need to be able to give you an accurate answer. Answering with anything else is just increasing the "noise" and making it harder to help you.

Comment: @Derek ONE child object

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely doing this the hard way.

You can make the SOQL query do the work by using [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm?q=aggregate) and appropriate grouping, ordering, and filtering.

What you'll end up writing is something like this

```sql
[SELECT Parent__c, Rank__c, SUM(currency__c) total 
FROM Child__c 
WHERE Parent__c = :parentIdList
GROUP BY Parent__c, Rank__c
ORDER BY Rank__c DESC]
```

That example is built to work with potentially many Parent records (because queries in loops are bad, and we should always expect to handle more than one record at a time).

Grouping by a field (or fields, in this example) is what allows us to get useful information back when we use an Aggregate Function like `SUM()`.

Given

| Parent__c | Rank__c | Currency__c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent1 | 1 | 100 |
| Parent1 | 1 | 200 |
| Parent1 | 2 | 500 |
| Parent2 | 6 | 400 |
| Parent2 | 7 | 100 |
| Parent2 | 6 | 600 |

The result would be

| Parent__c | Rank__c | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent1 | 2 | 500 |
| Parent1 | 1 | 300 |
| Parent2 | 7 | 100 |
| Parent2 | 6 | 1000 |

Note that the "total" in `SUM(currency__c) total` is a *field alias* and that dictates what the field name will be in the results. You don't *need* to alias any fields, but then aggregate functions show up in the result as "expr0", "expr1", and so on (which is less friendly to us humans).

It's not really possible for a query to say "tell me what the minimum rank is, and what the sum of that rank's currency is, for every parent in this list". Part of the reason why is that we can't use an aggregate function on a field that we're grouping by.

The next best thing though is to order by the rank. Ordering in either ascending or descending order would work. The ordering direction will have a small impact on the code that you write to handle the result of the query. I've chosen to sort in descending order here because it means there's ever so slightly less code in the loop when you process the results.

In this particular scenario, it means we can just keep overwriting data in a map without checking if there's already something in the map for that Parent__c record. By the time the loop ends, it'll have the sum of Currency__c for the lowest Rank__c children of that Parent. That's because ordering by Rank__c descending guarantees that the last item we loop over for a given Parent__c will be the lowest rank record(s) that parent has.

```java
// Use a map so we can overwrite data and ensure there aren't any duplicates
Map<Id, Parent__c> parentMap = new Map<Id, Parent__c>();

// Using an aggregate function means you'll get an "AggregateResult"
// You'll need to extract data using .get() and passing in the field name as a string
// That returns an "Object" that needs to be cast to a more specific type
for(AggregateResult ar :<the query from above>){

    // We don't care if there's already something in the map for this Id
    // Just overwrite the data and because we ordered descending we'll end
    //   up with the result from the lowest ranked child
    parentMap.put(
        Id = (Id)ar.get('Parent__c'),
        new Parent__c(
            Id = (Id)ar.get('Parent__c'),
            Currency__c = (Decimal)ar.get('total')
        )
    );
}
```